# nginx, php-fpm, and subfolders

Tags: nginx

First dive into nginx.  Possible lack of googlefoo/stack skills.  This should be super easy to solve but I'm really struggling with nginx's config.  I have yet to find documentation that makes sense to me and looks like 'best practices' style docs.

I'm trying to migrate a site from apache to nginx.  The site has a static html landing page that allows the user to pick a "sub-site" via link.  So they come in and hit the index.html (works just fine), then let's say they click the link for www.example.com/hhc/.  Instead of displaying the index.php that's in my hhc subfolder, they are presented with the download dialog for the actual hhc/index.php file instead of it being processed by the php-fpm backend.  However, If I type in the full URI (www.example.com/hhc/index.php), the php-fpm backend processes it just fine.

What am I missing?

Config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    root /var/www/html/;
    # whack trailing slashes
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

    location / {
        index index.html;
    }
    location /hhc {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /hhc/index.php?q=$request_uri;
    }

    # Process all .php files using the php-fpm local port 
    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;` instead of `try_files $uri $uri/ /hhc/index.php?q=$request_uri;` ?

Comment: Yes I have.  Doing that breaks my joomla instance in the hhc folder and it still offers the download dialog box when I go to www.example.com/hhc/.

Comment: Do you have `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;` in your `php.ini` settings?

Comment: I believe php-fpm uses /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini although I may be mistaken.  I have that setting in there.  I'm currently not using a global /etc/php.ini file.

Comment: Throw a dummy php file with the `phpinfo();` function inside. It's the best way to tell if a config is loaded.

Comment: I completely forgot that phpinfo gives you the path of the config it's using.  Thanks.  It is in fact using the one I want, /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini.

Comment: I found this but if it doesn't work I'm outta' ideas - http://programmersjunk.blogspot.ca/2013/11/nginx-multiple-sites-in-subdirectories.html - good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try adding index.php to the index directive in the location / block like this

```
location / {
    index index.html /index.php;
}
```